# Can't change Mockito version in POM of springboot project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, mockito, dependency-management

I'm interested with

[35. Custom verification failure message (Since 2.0.0)](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html)

But somehow I cant use it in my Maven project.

[image: no description method]

**POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- potrzebujemy nowszej wersji mockito -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Uncompilable code:**

```
@Test
public void testCustomVerificationFailureMessage(){
    List mock = mock(List.class);

    BDDMockito.given(mock.get(0)).willReturn("string");

    mock.get(0);

    verify(mock, times(1).description("metoda powinna wykonać się tylko jeden raz")).get(0);
}
```

Am I missing something? it seems that older version still kicks in.

**SOLUTION:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Mockito</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.106-beta</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What happens when you type the code and compile? Could you post a minimal, but complete example, as code, and not as a picture?

Comment: @JBNizet uncompilable source code.

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example, as code.

Comment: You exclude mockito-core but depend on mockito-all. Springboot likes to nail down all dependency versions, maybe thats the problem. Maybe you can just define a version property, see https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest beta version of Mockito is 2.0.106-beta. But mockito-all is stuck at version 2.0.2-beta, where this method doesn't exist.

Use mockito-core instead of mockito-all, and use the latest version, where this method exists.

Comment: thats exactly what I did just second ago ;)